# worker role with TCPListener stops working

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have this very basic worker role running, listening to a incoming TCP connections and processing them. But for some reason now fails after a while.. seems like it is no longer receiving data... no exception seen in the trace.
Now make it synchronous... still the same problem.

The idea is to accept an HTTP request and give a 302 redirection.

When I connect to it via a telnet on port 80 it works.

As soon as I use a browser, it starts failing quickly.

When I try again afterwards on port 80, no response anymore.

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        IPEndPoint ipin = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Server"].IPEndpoint;
        server = new TcpListener(ipin);
        server.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        server.Start();

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                HandleSyncConnection(client);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Server stopped. Exception:" + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
    private void HandleSyncConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Setup reader/writer 
            NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream, Encoding.ASCII);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(netStream, Encoding.ASCII);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;

            byte[] baBuffer = new byte[10000];
            byte[] baHeader = { 13, 10, 13, 10 };
            Int32 iTotalBytesReceived = 0;
            Int32 iHeaderFound = 0;

            while (iTotalBytesReceived < baBuffer.Length)
            {
              Int32 iBytesReceived = netStream.Read(baBuffer, iTotalBytesReceived, baBuffer.Length - iTotalBytesReceived);
              if (iBytesReceived == 0)
                   break;
              for (int i = 0; i < iBytesReceived; i++)
              {
                  if (baBuffer[iTotalBytesReceived + i] == baHeader[iHeaderFound])
                        iHeaderFound++;
                  else
                      iHeaderFound = 0;
              }
              iTotalBytesReceived += iBytesReceived;
              if (iHeaderFound == baHeader.Length)
                 break;
              Thread.Sleep(50);
            }

            String strResponse;
            Trace.TraceInformation("Request received");
            strResponse = "HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect" + EOL + "Location: http://www.google.com");
            strResponse += EOL + "Content-Type: text/html" + EOL + "Cache-Control: no-cache" + EOL + "Connection: close" + EOL + "Content-Length: 0" + EOL + EOL;
            writer.Write(strResponse);
            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();
            // Done! 
            client.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            Trace.TraceError("Server stopped in the handling of sync " + e.Message);
          }
    }
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? What is it doing when it "stops working"?

Comment: parhaps you get a  "normal" exception? Try adding:
        catch (Exception se)
        {
               Trace.WriteLine("Server stopped. Exception:" + se.Message);
               return;
        }

Comment: When it "stops working", it can no longer accept connections.. there is already a try/catch in the code, but indeed just for the SocketException. Let me change that.

Comment: Just a general question.. this code shows that it is "running" in the Azure manager, but still not a single TCP connect is accepted..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by running, but maybe you need to "protect" you listening loop by try excecpting withing the while(and just logging it and not stop listening). The acceptcpclient blocks until there is a connection, so there is no need for the Sleep(10). Mind you that when the Process(client) runs no new connections are excepted, perhaps you should use a seperate thread for this. You can break out of the while loop by checking for cancel blocking exception (10004) in case of a stop server.

Comment: FInally, I figured out that my code crashed on reading data since "unknown" client were accessing my service.. so I changed that one. I also took the advice from Ceelie and make it async. It now runs 50% of the time. See the changes to the code.

Comment: The way you are doing async is made synchronous by the event handle. That does not help over being synchronous in the first place.

Comment: I assumed by putting EndAcceptTcpClient(result) and       connectionWaitHandle.Set() early in the code, it would make the code faster.. not true ? something I should change to handle more connections?

Comment: Make the accept loop synchronous. That's just one thread, you can burn that one. Make HandleAsyncConnection asynchronous. Or, if you have just a few connections (dozens, or low hundreds and low throughput) just use a thread per connection. Anyway, to debug the problem log exceptions that are occurring as part of HandleAsyncConnection.

Comment: ok I made it synchronous and add the HTTP handler for the redirect... still no clue why it fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not on how your application is implemented.

Have you consider the Azure load balance timeout?

Here is a good blog post detailing it:

[Windows Azure Load Balancer Timeout Details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/12/windows-azure-load-balancer-timeout-details.aspx)

Azure will stop your application after a minute or so independent of your implementation.

Take a look at that and see if that is problem that you are facing.

Regards